# open textfield after click on span does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, edit-in-place

I am not able to create an edit in place feature with JavaScript/ jQuery. I could not use the plugin editinplace, because I need to put a datepicker on it. My code below does not work for some strange reason:

```
function editImpfDatumImpfung1Clicked(sender)
{
    var sText = $(this).text();
    var sId = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).attr("id", "tobechanged");
    $(this).after('<input type="text" id="' + sId + '" value="' + sText + '" />');
    $(this).remove();
    bImpfung1Clicked = true;
    $("#" + sId).focus();
    $("#" + sId).datepicker(datepickerOptions);

    if (bFirstRegisterImpfung1 === true)
    {
        firstRegisterImpfung1();
        bFirstRegisterImpfung1 = false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $elem = $("span[id^='impfung_1['");

    if ($elem.length > 0)
    {
        bFirstRegisterImpfung1 = true;
        $elem.click(editImpfDatumImpfung1Clicked);
    }
});
```

Edit:

No Errors in console.

`console.log($("#" + sId).val());` causes `undefined`

Edit 2:
Just needed to escape the id like this:

```
sId = sId.replace(/[[]/g,'\\[');
sId = "#" + sId.replace(/]/g,'\\]');
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: any error on `console`

Comment: provide error will help to solve your problem.

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: What's the relevant/representative HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you have a typo in the following line:

```
$elem = $("span[id^='impfung_1['");
```

try this instead:

```
$elem = $("span[id^='impfung_1']");
```

Comment: And the single quote?